# Get sessionId using request Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to get the sessionId, so i can do other requests.
So i looked in the Firefox Network monitor (Ctrl+Shift+Q) and saw this:

[image]

So i wondered how i could do the request in python 3 and tried things like this:

```
import requests
payload = {'uid' : 'username',
      'pwd' : 'password'}

r = requests.get(r'http://192.168.2.114(cgi-bin/wwwugw.cgi', data=payload)

print r.text
```

But I always get "Response [400]".
If the request is correct, I should get something like this:

[image]

Thanks
Alex

Comment: It should be `requests.post`. and you have to pass every item using the same format.meaning, you have to include `method`, `params` parts as well. also make sure to enter the correct url. the one in your question has a typo.

Comment: @Himal so I did enter the method param aswell and now i'm getting Errno 133 (payload = {'method':'ugw-login',
 'params':{'uid' : 'gw',
 'pwd' : 'GATEWAY'}})

Comment: Could you please update your question to include the latest version of the code you have and the complete error message you are getting ?

Comment: Also, can you see any cookies being sent on that POST request ? Additionally, you might have to include other request headers such as "Referer". you can test it by removing one of the headers and posting it again (using the tool you used on your first image) . do this with every header.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a session, which will handle redirects and cookies for you:

```
import requests
payload = {'uid' : 'username',
          'pwd' : 'password'}

with requests.Session() as session:
    r = session.post(r'http://192.168.2.114(cgi-bin/wwwugw.cgi', data=payload)

    print(r.json)
```

This way you don't explicitly need to get the `sessionId`, but if you still want to, you can access the returned `JSON` as a dictionary.

Comment: thanks for the answer, well it's not working, I'm getting Errno 133. Any other way i could do this?

Answer (score 2):

if you want to get the Session ID you can use `Session()` from the `requests` library:

```
URL = "Some URL here"

client = requests.Session()
client.get(URL)
client.cookies['sessionid']
```

Answer (score 1):

Although it's not very clear from your question, but I've noticed few issues with what you are trying to accomplish.

1. If you are using session authentication, then you are suppose the send session_id as a `Cookie` header, which you aren't doing.
2. 400 response code means bad request, not authentication required. Why are you sending data in `get` request to begin with? There's a difference between data and query params.

Comment: Oh yes, forgot to say that i'm a noob in Python

Comment: Yeah all of us commit mistakes like that. You need to frame your question a little better though.