# How to vote a photo with requests?

Tags: python, python-requests

Hello i want vote a picture from a website and i tried somethings but i didn't see any vote

This is url of photo: https://woobox.com/nvk7uh/gallery/B47CxJE1PoU

And a picture what i see when i listen it with network:

Payloads: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pPxzx.png)

Headers: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpdU7.png)

And my code i didn't put id because i don't know how to access it:

```
import requests

link = "https://woobox.com/nvk7uh/gallery/B47CxJE1PoU"
request_url = 'https://woobox.com/nvk7uh/vote/add'
session = requests.session()

response = session.get(link, headers=fake_header)
print(response.status_code)

vote_payload = {

    'signed_request': 'false'
}
    
vote_headers = {

    'accept': '*/*',
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/105.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
    'referer': link,
    'x-requested-with': 'XMLHttpRequest'
}

voter_response = session.post(request_url, data=vote_payload, headers=vote_headers)
print('Vote Status: ' + str(voter_response.status_code))
print(voter_response.text)
time.sleep(3)
```

What do you think about this code? what is problem?

Comment: When you GET the page, the server reads the cookie it has set. If it does not exist it sets it. The cookie contains a unique session id. Inspect the network activity in your browser and you will see it. If you want to vote multiple times, every time you should: 1. GET the page and save the session id. 2. POST the vote by inserting such id in the headers

Comment: @Pynchia Hello pls can you show me how to do this? im new at coding and i want learn how to save session and post vote by inserting id in headers?

Comment: i found this but not helped: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43873147/get-sessionid-using-request-python

Comment: this page may have more complex system because it remembers my vote even if I run browser in `private mode` which doesn't have my previous cookies and settings. It also remembers if I run page with different browsers Chrome, Firefox. It may uses IP to recognize it and this may need to use `proxy servers`

Comment: Im already using proxy but same i just putted a basic code

Comment: @furas i just have problems with voting it

Comment: this server may have complex system to check users and this can makes problem to vote it with normal `requests`. It may be simpler to do it with [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/)

Comment: it may have this ID in some part of `<script>` in HTML. It may need complex code to extract this value.

Comment: so is it impossible? :(